# What do I need to do for the node-horseman to work on the azure?

Tags: node.js, azure, npm, web-scraping, node-horseman

The node-horseman works perfectly on my local server, but when I put it on azure it does not work.
Node-horseman is a headless-browser module for node.js.
I think the azure is blocking access from external links, but how could I unlock this?

```
const Horseman = require('node-horseman');
const users = ['PhantomJS', 'nodejs'];
var express = require('express'),
    http = require('http'),
    app = express();
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send("Deu certo!");
    console.log("Funcionou");
});
app.get('/twitter/', function (req, res) {
    var retorno = ``;
    var extracoes = 0;
    console.log("aqui");
    users.forEach((user) => {
        const horseman = new Horseman();
        horseman
            .open(`http://twitter.com/${user}`)
            .text('.ProfileNav-item--followers .ProfileNav-value')
            .then((text) => {
                retorno += `${user}: ${text}<br>`;
                extracoes ++;
                if (extracoes == users.length) {
                    res.send(retorno);
                }
            })
            .close();
    });
});
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're hosted on Azure App Service, be aware of this wiki here - https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#unsupported-frameworks

> Other scenarios that are not supported:
>   PhantomJS/Selenium: tries to connect to local address, and also uses GDI+.

Deploy your application to [Cloud Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-nodejs-develop-deploy-app) or a [VM](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/virtual-machines/) instead. [App Service on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-linux-using-custom-docker-image) should also work if you bring your own container (with PhantomJS and all dependencies).